# document saving on resign active expired with error Error

Tags: ios, uidocument

What does this mean:

2019-10-02 09:24:48.976268+0300 UP[2286:1341304] [UIDocumentLog] document saving on resign active expired with error Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=1 "Assertion has already been invalidated" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Assertion has already been invalidated}:  fileURL: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A689FB2D-38EA-4D90-A65F-8BB0D02C8770/Documents/myfilename documentState: [Normal]

and how do I flush the changes staged for UIDocument
autosave presumabley to avoid this

save has some ungodly seemingly useless signature
with url, etc

all I need is to speed up the uidocument save,
in particular to avoid abomination such as this on the device console